# Making target when writing a question a mandatory selection?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

I've seen questions where it wasn't clear at first sight (and also not at second or third), if at all, what they were about. So, wouldn't it be advantageous if there were a list of "main" targets at question creation, with at least one selection mandatory, which then are [transformed to the appropriate tag](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tags), e.g.:

> ☐ Automotive
> ☐ Desktop application
> ☐ Internet of Things
> ☐ Mobile application
> ☐ Web application
> ☐ ... [something else? Open for discussion...]
>
> Specify details (device, operating system, application details, ...) in up to four tags below.

[Sorted alphabetically here, perhaps by relevance in real.]

Without the need to ask for clarification in comments (potentially back and forth) I think this would lead to:

- quicker answers,
- even more answers (since there could be readers who know an or *the* answer, but leave since they don't dare to ask to avoid the potential "shame of ignorance")

Added value:

There's a stronger hint to use tags than one `#####` header without bold, one sentence in small-font and a text field, which disappear from the viewport at the bottom bit by bit and *completely* after you entered *the third line* in the question's text area (in my env at least: 24", FF with 3 bars at the top, 100 % zoom).